# Sending PHP mails from localhost behind a proxy server

Tags: php, email, localhost

I want to send mails using php script in localhost. Via google I found switchmailer. I tried the following code using swiftmailer.

```
<?php
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
  ->setUsername('gmailid@gmail.com')
  ->setPassword('gmailpassword')
  ;
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

// Create a message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
  ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))
  ->setTo(array('mail1@gmail.com', 'mail2@gmail.com' => 'A name'))
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
  ;

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);

?>
```

The code was giving error in lase line `$result = $mailer->send($message);`

The php error log file contains following info

> [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception
>   'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection could not be
>   established with host smtp.gmail.com [Network is unreachable #101]' in
>   /home/shashwat001/public_html/swift/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:259\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /home/shashwat001/public_html/swift/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php(64):
>   Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->_establishSocketConnection()\n#1
>   /home/shashwat001/public_html/swift/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(115):
>   Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize(Array)\n#2
>   /home/shashwat001/public_html/swift/lib/classes/Swift/Mailer.php(80):
>   Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start()\n#3
>   /home/shashwat001/public_html/swift/index.php(31):
>   Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message))\n#4 {main}\n  thrown in
>   /home/shashwat001/public_html/swift/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php
>   on line 259

The reason seems to be that I am connected to a LAN network so behind a proxy server. Nothing is there much on net regarding proxy settings in switchmailer.

Is there any way to send mails anywhere outside LAN using localhost behind proxy server?

Comment: What kind of proxy is it? SOCKS? SSH port forward? SQUID?

Comment: It is http/https proxy

Comment: not sure you could tunnel smtp over port 80. http isn't exactly set up to support the smtp command sequence necessary to actually connect to a remote server and "upload" an email.

Answer (score 1):

The correct port for Google Mail is 465, Google also uses SSL for connections to Gmail.

Comment: Got the same php error using port 465. I think smtp connection can be made unless I define proxy settings somewhere which I am not able to find.

Comment: You should change the third parameter to 'ssl' on the newInstance function.